# How do you implement options for your C programs in Unix Terminal?

Tags: c

I want to add a -r option to my c program. So that when it is used in the command line in the terminal it will trigger a different operation for my program. How do I tell my c program that when it sees the text -r in particular that it will jump to the piece of code that will do that alternate functionality?

What I have done so far: 
So far I have setup my c program to handle files, but not options so my program is able to handle text files in this manner it formats the text files in some way and prints it out stdout:

./p4.out < sometextfile

./p4.out sometextfile

From C by Discovery by Foster I figured out how to do this by using the FILE pointer and the following 
form of the main program:

```
void main(argc, char *argv[])
```

In my code I have if statements to indicate whether or not there is an input file to be processed or just read from standard input via the following if statements:

```
if(argc == 1){

//do something with standard in (stdin)

}

if(argc == 2){

//do something with one file parameter (sometextfile)

}
```

The functionality I want to add:
In particular my c program should be able to take parameters like this:

```
./p4.out -r
./p4.out -r sometextfile
./p4.out sometextfile -r
```

The -r functionality should be read by my main program and then indicate that the characters in the text file should be reversed. C by discovery 2nd edition doesn't mention how to add options to c programs so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Have a look here: http://argtable.sourceforge.net/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone. Surprisingly my C book doesn't contain getopt() so I was confused if there was anyway to do this with my C program. I knew it could be done because the unix utilities have that.

Comment: I don't really want to setup a new question for this since it's probably really simple, so does anyone know how I could remove the "./" and the ".out" to run my c program in the unix terminal. I want it too look like a unix utility so it should look like this: p4 sometextfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by iterating over the arguments provided by the user in the *argv* array, comparing them to your argument values, and setting flags to indicate that an argument has been used.

```
int reverse = 0;
const char* file = NULL;
for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
{
    if( strcmp( argv[i], "-r" ) == 0 )
    {
        reverse = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        file = argv[i];
    }
}

if( reverse )
{
    // Reverse the text
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rhuidean, for spelling it out for me. I'm new to C and they are just introducing it to us in upper division CS. I've been programming in Java for most of my lower division. So some of this stuff in completely new to me.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that all the strings in argv are strings terminated with a null character otherwise strcmp will not work.

Comment: Yes, the strings in argv are C-strings which are null-terminated; you can rely on this. You may notice that I skip the first element of argv as this typically contains the name of the program and will not contain any behaviour-dependent arguments.

Comment: I don't really want to setup a new question for this since it's probably really simple, so do you know how I could remove the "./" and the ".out" to run my c program in the unix terminal. I want it too look like a unix utility so it should look like this: p4 sometextfile

Comment: When attempting to run a program, your shell will reference the PATH environment variable in order to find it if it cannot resolve the program path from the name itself. You can either change PATH so that it also references the directory where your program exists or you can link/move your program somewhere on PATH. I recommend /usr/local/bin as this is the traditional location for user-created programs.

Also, when compiling your program, use -o to specify the output filename. i.e g++ main.cpp -o myprogram.

Comment: edit your shells `.rc` and make the file an `alias` ([how to](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ualias.htm)) ` this will remove `./` when you call the program, it also removes the `.out` because you specify what name the alias will have.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html)

If the syntax for the command line arguments to your program is *simple enough*, you can **simply pick the arguments off from argv by hand**. But unless your program takes a fixed number of arguments, or all of the arguments are interpreted in the same way (as file names, for example), you are usually better off using getopt (see [Getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt)) or argp_parse (see [Argp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html#Argp)) to do the parsing.

Comment: Okay. Hmm I know it's an array pointers so yeah I guess that could work.

Comment: Id recommend using getopt, the [example code](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt) demonstrates how it works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You either work out the logic for your particular program, or use a library like the ones described here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html#Parsing-Program-Arguments

Answer (score 0):

if you simple compile the program by using cc command or by gcc then by default executable file name is a.out. If you want to remove that one at the time of compilation you can give any name that you want. And the second thing ./ meaning your current directory. I don't know how to execute without using ./ .
May be it help full for you

Comment: Thanks for that tidbit of information. Helps me refine my understanding. Yeah, I know ./ is current directory I looked it up, it just looks ugly in my eyes and I wanted to run my program without it. XD